# Mesh deforming when add bezier modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

I´m trying to model a race track using a bezier curve, but, when I add modifiers -> array -> curve I get this :

[image]

What should I check for to get the mesh following the curve correctly ?
Thankyou

Comment: can you upload the .blend?

Comment: Such offsets are often related to origins mismatching. Could you show where is each object's origin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Carlo, looks like the mesh and the curve don't share the same exact origin coordinates in the scene.

Make sure the have the same origin, and that the origin of the mesh object is sanely placed relative to it's geometry.

With the mesh object selected <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to Geometry*, or manually place it where you want it using your 3D cursor and then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to 3D cursor*

After that make sure your object is aligned with the curve by selecting the bezier, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*, then select your mesh <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*.

Optionally if you want a simple circular section consider using the bevel option directly on your track curve, or for more complex shapes perhaps a 2D bezier curve in the shape of the section of your road/track.

**EDIT** Upon further inspection to your file there seems to be something wrong with that bezier curve object, not quite sure what it is exactly, but whatever it is it's messing up the curve modifier.

Anyway to solve whatever problems you are encountering follow all the above steps, make sure your track curve has its origin at the scene center (world coordinate 0,0,0) by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to center the cursor, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to 3D cursor*

Now clear all the transforms on or "section" mesh with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and then clear scale with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*. Make sure it is centered in the scene origin just like the track's origin.

To "fix" your bezier curve track, whatever is messed up about it, just add a new spline object, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Curve* > *Bezier* and join the original to this new one (not the other way around) by selecting the track spline, then the new one and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.

Then enter edit mode and delete the new small unwanted segment. If you now rebuild your modifier stack in the mesh now it should work ok.

[image: Track fixed]

Comment: eromod, yes I could upload the .blend. Is it possible here ?

Comment: Duarte, I follow your instructions, but I got a even more weird result... This is making me crazy.

Comment: You can upload your file using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1258" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1258/)

Comment: Ok, updated my answer, you should edit your original question and add the file link to it.

Comment: Perfect !!!!! That did the trick perfectly. Thankyou so much Duarte !!!!!!