# curve modifier moves mesh

Tags: bezier-curves

As soon as curve is attached.

[image]

I need it to not move away. I have already joined hip with the rest of the spine but it deforms too much. Can anyone suggest how could i accomplish the same without curve modifiers? Thank you so much for your patience.

Moving top handle dislodges.

[image: moving top handle dislodges]

As soon as curve starts top part dislodges

[image: as soon as curve starts top part dislodges[![][2]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj8LY.png).png

Comment: when you are using the curve modifier you have to make sure that the curve and the object's origins are in the same place. An alternative to using curves would be to create an armature, it will give you more control over the deformation.

Comment: This has been asked countless times, also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51909/mesh-deforming-when-add-bezier-modifier

Comment: I know...even following the instructions...matching origins...i still get the mesh going somewhere else...its so upsetting...i have to thank everyone over here that is always so nice in helping me, a novice...in different issues. thank you thank you thank you

Comment: Also make sure you turn off the *Path Animation* option in your curve