How to model an object to follow a curve/path
I am wondering how to extrude the highlighted object to make it follow the black path towards the ground?
I have tried using bezier curves and an array and that doesnt give me the result I want. I need it to look smooth and that it transitions like the rest of the object.
Thank you!



https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51909/mesh-deforming-when-add-bezier-modifier/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49639/how-to-smooth-an-arrayed-object-so-the-breaks-between-objects-are-less-obvious/49651#49651

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ? I have to confess that I do not see "a black path". I am also confuse by "extrusion" and "array". You can extrude a curve along an other curve. You can instance an object along a curve. But I do not know how to extrude an object along a curve.

](https://blend-exchange.com/b/YpKprKYr/
I am trying to extrude or model the highlighted object to fit the same curve/orientation as the black object if that makes sense.

Do you want to preserve the complex structure inside the highlighted object, or is it enough to keep a simplified outline ? Because there are very small details in this object that are invisible in the view you are showing. A Level Of Detail decision...

Keeping outline of it is okay, I dont need all the inside details just the shell of the outside

(Using Blender 3.6.12)
Approach

The outline of the object to extrude (in light orange at the far right side) can be simplified in a right-angled trapezoid. It is expected to rotate only around the vertical (Z) axis as it is displaced along the "black path" (in light blue at the back) to remain perpendicular to this "wall" whatever its curvature. So to use it as Bevel Object along a Curve is not recommended because it will be perpendicular to this curve, without control of the Z axis.
Alternatively, a sequence of two extrusions, firstly of ridge edges, then of the resulting faces, is proposed to make the light green shape.
Procedure

1. To simplify the demonstration, only the "path" (in blue) and the trapezoidal object (in orange) are copied in a new Scene.
2. It is to notice that the topology of the "path" is quite complex, with many elongated triangles. These make the selection of the ridge not straightforward in Edit Mode.

3. To select the ridge to extrude, firstly the top faces of the "path" are selected, from the menu Select > Select Linked > Linked Flat Faces with Sharpness set to 10°.
4. Other faces are hidden from the menu Mesh > Show/Hide > Hide Unselected.

5. Then first and last edges of the ridge to extrude are selected. Edges in-between are selected from the menu Select > Select Linked > Shortest Path.
6. As before, other edges are hidden.

7. Selected edges are copied without displacement from the menu Mesh > Duplicate.
8. Eventually, the ridge to extrude is transferred as a new object from the menu Mesh > Separate > Selection.

9. After the view is aligned with the X axis and centred on the back of the trapezoidal object, the ridge is extruded in Z direction. The displacement is adjusted to match the largest height of the trapezoidal object.

10. Resulting normals orientation can be righted from the menu Mesh > Normals > Flip.

11. After the view is aligned with the Z axis, these faces are extruded from the menu Face > Extrude Faces Along Normals. The displacement is adjusted to match the length of the trapezoidal object.

12. Edges of the bottom front ridge are selected from the menu Select > Select Loops > Edge Loops.

13. After the view is set to Orthographic and centred on the small side of the trapezoidal object, those edges are moved up in Z direction. The displacement is adjusted to match the smallest height of the trapezoidal object.
14. The remaining gap (between green and orange objects) can be visually closed by moving the last vertical green edge next to the trapezoidal object.
Resources
(Blender 3.6.12+)
